# Is resampling necessary while calculating Normalized Difference Built-up Index (NDBI) on Sentinel 2

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, satellite

The formula for calculating NDBI using Sentinel-2 bands are as follows:

```
Band 11 - Band 8 / Band 11 + Band 8
```

However, bands 11 and 8 have a spatial resolution of 20 metres and 10 metres respectively. Does this mean that I will have to resample the bands such that they are of the same resolution before proceeding with the formula, or can I go ahead with this formula without resampling?
I am using Google Earth Engine for the analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your needs.

GEE can work with different image resolutions, with the results defaulting to the highest.

Conversely, you can use B8A, which is very similar to B8 wavelength, but is at 20 meters resolution, so you can remove any sub-pixel uncertainty